# What is the layer on my wall and peels off when wet and how do I fix/replace it?

Tags: walls, painting, paint, lath-and-plaster

I was about to re-paint the ceiling of my closet. I am not sure when this was done the last time but the structure itself is lath & plaster from 1929.

After putting on some paint, it seems one layer started to peel and revealing some yellow-ish underneath. The layer felt like "cardboard". I do not think it is wallpaper because there are no patterns and it feels thicker (about 1mm).

Now with a putty knife, it comes off easily. But sure enough not everywhere. Sometimes it basically comes off by itself, sometimes it's stuck.

I am going to assume it's best to just scrape off everything with the putty knife (I meanwhile scraped off a lot where it came off easily).

Notes:

- Now I also see on the closet *wall* many places where it looks "blistering" ... probably the same there.
- I have re-painted many places in the house but never experienced this. The closet seems to be "different" than the other walls.

Questions:

- What is this layer?
- Any plausible explanation why it's only in the closet and nowhere else?
- Shall I try to remove everything with putty knife?
- Shall I pre-emptively remove it also from the walls?
- How do I fix/replace this mess in the easiest, least costly way? I doubt I can just paint over the yellow part...

This is how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Could it have been wallpaper?

Comment: I don’t know, shouldn’t wallpaper have some patterns?

Comment: Wallpaper might have an embossed pattern, but it’s also possible that it’s flat and has been painted enough that any artwork has disappeared.

Comment: Assuming it's wallpaper, how would you proceed?

Comment: Plain, un-patterned wallpaper is sometimes used to hide small cracks and other wall or ceiling imperfections prior to painting.

Comment: @divB - Wet, scrape, wet some more, scrape some more (you bet the drift) until all the wallpaper, paste, & sizing is removed.  Yeah it's a PITA.  The good part is that if the ceiling & wall surface is really plaster, you can be very liberal with the water, which is not the case if you have modern paper-faced sheetrock.

Comment: @SteveSh Thanks. After this, can I directly apply paint or do I need to put additional layer(s) before paint? Also, would you pro-actively do the same with the walls or just leave them be?

Comment: Assuming you don't damage the plaster coat, you should be able prime, then apply a top coat.  A lot depends on the condition of the plaster surface.  Take your time.  It took me a week or better to get all the wall & glue off of plaster walls in a small bath.

Comment: Got it. So if you look on my picture, I can directly prime and then paint on the brown surface (which is plaster)? No other special things needed?

Comment: If it's just plaster, then that should be OK.  I will, however, defer to the pro painters here.